# Erase Everything on key press

Tags: security, ubuntu, odroid

I have a application that is running Ubuntu on a Odroid (Single Board Computer). I want to secure it in such a way that any end user cannot enter into the operating system or change anything. I have two solution in mind: -

1. Disable all usb ports and whenever a HDMI is connected a specific application opens up
2. Constantly check if any key is pressed. On any key press Delete everything

To Summarize my application is quite heavy and I cant run any further task that is CPU Hungry. HDMI can't be disabled as I need to show a GUI

Comment: why not disable human device (keyboard, mouse,etc) inputs?

Comment: What is the purpose of this protection? Why do you want to do this, what is the threat you are trying to mitigate? Based on your description, it sounds hopelessly impossible, and not the right approach.

Comment: The main purpose is that I don't want the user to view my code and other configuration data